# DROP PROCEDURE/CREATE PROCEDURE in TRY/CATCH block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008 and above, if I am altering a stored procedure, I can issue a

```
DROP PROCEDURE foo IF EXISTS
```

command. If the procedure exists then it is dropped and if it doesn't exist then no error is thrown and processing continues. Is it worth wrapping the DROP PROCEDURE/CREATE PROCEDURE combination (when I am updating the code) in a TRY/CATCH block "just in case" or does the DROP PROCEDURE not return an error if something blocks it from the dropping the procedure?

Comment: Why are you dropping a procedure if you're altering it; why not the `ALTER PROC` syntax?

Comment: Also, that syntax isn't valid for SQL Server, the correct syntax is `DROP PROC IF EXISTS [ProcName]`; however that was introduced in SQL Server 2016 (it wasn't, and still isn't, available in SQL Server 2008).

Comment: Mainly because our corporate t-sql IDE (IDERA Rapid SQL 17.0) extracts existing code in that fashion. SSMS doesn't, but this one does. I was just curious if the DROP PROCEDURE will return an error or not and I didn't find anything when I researched the issue. ALTER is a much better option, but not available at this point.

Comment: @Larnu The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says that PROC is an option and that it is available from 2008 on.

Comment: This only works for SQL Server 2016 or higher. If you are on that version, you can also just use `CREATE OR ALTER ...` to avoid the `DROP` entirely.

Comment: @JasonW I hadn't seen that command before. We are only just moving to SQL Server 2016 and that is a handy feature. Passing it on to the other devs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the `IF EXISTS` only was added in SQL Server 2016 or higher:

> IF EXISTS
>
> **Applies to:** SQL Server ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x) through version).

```
DROP PROC IF EXISTS foo -- No error handling needed
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

If you are using SQL Server 2016 SP1 or higher, you don't even need to `DROP` anymore since you can add `CREATE OR ALTER` when creating your procedure.

> OR ALTER
>
> **Applies to:** Azure SQL Database, SQL Server (starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP1).

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC foo ... -- No drop needed
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

If you are not using SQL Server 2016 or higher, then you are are stuck with "classic" methods:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('foo') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC foo
GO

CREATE PROC foo ...
```

Comment: For the classic method, is the TRY/CATCH model useful? Just in case the DROP fails.

Comment: I never have. The only error you are likely to get is if the PROC does not exist, which (1) is handled with the `IF` statement and (2) even if it runs does not stop execution of the block of code. In this code: `DROP PROC DoesNotExist; PRINT 'Runs anyway'`, both statements fully run.

Comment: `DROP PROCEDURE`/`CREATE PROCEDURE` is not a good pattern to begin with because you lose any permissions already defined, and any active clients that call this procedure stop working in the brief interval the procedure no longer exists. (I'm assuming that's not actually what you want, if it is, drop away...) Prior to SQL Server 2016, the best approach is arguably `IF OBJECT_ID('foo') IS NULL EXECUTE ('CREATE PROCEDURE foo AS BEGIN RETURN END')`. Now you can unconditionally issue an `ALTER`.